# Parsing XML document missing enclosing parent entity

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I want to process an XML document that lacks an overarching enclosing entity.  (Yes, that's the file I'm given.  No, I didn't create it.)  For example:

```
<DeviceInfo>
  <Greeting>Crunchy bacon!</Greeting>
</DeviceInfo>
<InstantaneousDemand>
  <TimeStamp>0x1c722845</TimeStamp>
</InstantaneousDemand>
<InstantaneousDemand>
  <TimeStamp>0x1c72284a</TimeStamp>
</InstantaneousDemand>
```

When I parse the file using Nokogiri's XML method, it (predictably) only reads the first entity:

```
>> doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("x.xml"))
>> doc.children.count
=> 1
doc.text
=> "\n  Crunchy bacon!\n"
```

I *could* read the file as a string and wrap a fake enclosing entity around the whole thing, but that seems heavy handed.  Is there a better way to get Nokogiri to read in all the entities?

Comment: Wrapping a document with `"<xml>#{ File.read("x.xml") }</xml>"` is entirely valid and not heavy handed at all. The only concern is that the file is being slurped, but that same concern would exist using a DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might create a [`DocumentFragment`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/DocumentFragment) rather than `Document` (especially taking into account that your content is *actually* a document fragment):

```
▶ doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse File.read("x.xml")
#⇒ #<Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment:0x14efa38 name="#document-fragment" 
#    ...
#  #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14ef68c name="InstantaneousDemand"
#    ...
▶ doc.children.count
#⇒ 6
```

Hope it helps.